# GAE - task returning 500 on first attempt and 200 on next attempt

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, flask, task-queue, urlfetch

I am trying to send emails via mandrill inside push taskqueue. On the first attempt of the task, the email is sent, urlfetch.fetch results is 200 but task fails and is queued for the second attempt. On second attempt, mail is re-sent and task completes with a 200 status.  Here is code snippet

```
try:
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url=<MANDRILL_SEND_URL>,
                            method=urlfetch.POST,
                            deadline=60,
                            payload=json.dumps(mail_params))
    if result.status_code == 200:
        # return 200 response (using flask with GAE)
        return "", 200  
except Exception as e:
        logging.error("100 - Exception while sending email: {0}".format(e))
```

Email is critical to flow, so I need to make sure email is sent so re-tries of tasks are needed.

Comment: What is the error message you get in the log ?

Comment: logs for first time

    `INFO    "POST <task_url> HTTP/1.1" 500 -
    WARNING  taskqueue_stub.py:1980] Task task1 failed to execute. This task will retry in 100.000 seconds`

second time
    `INFO    "POST <task_url> HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: I suggest you add some logging in your task code.  Consider trapping the Error, and logging it if you can.

Comment: edited question with exception handling. Nothing new in logs.

Comment: See if you task will run if you do not attempt to send the email.  Still do the json.dumps.  You need to try and see what is causing the failure to run.  You may also want to look at an alternate mail service